# Excel drawing error

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-recovery, charts

I have an Excel file that is in the Excel 2016 file format (File.xlsx). Suddenly file hang and start showing not responding after few minutes file restart automatically after that I receive an error message that Excel cannot open and whether I want to repair it.  If I say Yes to repair it, the file opens, and I receive the following error message:

```
Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing unreadable content.
Repaired Records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part (Drawing shape)
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: That is not exactly an error message. Excel just says that it recovered the file by getting rid of the diagram (which possibly got corrupted when Excel crashed for the first time). What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about it. Save as a new file and continue. If it keeps doing it, save as xlsb (binary) or old xls file. Test and resave as xlsx.

Last resort would be to unzip the xlsx file and manually deleting that file. Rezip and rename to .xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to re-save as a new file format and confirm if you can open it.
2. Follow this article about repairing Workbook: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53